# How to apply a long set of conditions on a pandas dataframe efficiently - stock backtesting

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I'm attempting to apply a long set of conditions and operations onto a pandas dataframe (see the dataframe below with VTI, upper, lower, etc). I attempted to use apply, but I was having a lot of trouble doing so.). My current solution (which works perfectly) relies on a for loop iterating through the dataframe. But my sense is that this is an inefficient way to complete my simulation. I'd appreciate help on the design of my code.

```
  VTI upper lower sell   buy AboveUpper BelowUpper BelowLower date tokens order
0 44.58 NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-15  5    0
1 44.29 NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-18  5    1
2 44.42 NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-19  5    2
3 44.88 NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-20  5    3
4 45.24 NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-21  5    4
```

if I wanted to run a bunch of conditions and forloops like the below and run the function below (the get row data function) only if the row meets the conditions provided, how would I do so?

My intuition says to use .apply() but I'm not clear how to do it within this scenario. With all the if's and for-loops combined, it's a lot of rows. The below actually outputs an entirely new dataframe. I'm wondering if there are more efficient/better ways to think about the design of this simulation/stock backtesting process.

Get row data simply obtains key data from the dataframe and computes certain information based on globals (like how much capital I have already, how many stocks I have already) and spits out a list. I append all these lists into a dataframe that I call the portfolio.

I've given a snippet of the code that I've already made using a for-loop.

```
 ##This is only for the sell portion of the algorithm
 if val['sell'] == True and tokens == maxtokens: 
        print 'nothign to sell'


if val['sell'] == True and tokens < maxtokens: 
    print 'sellprice', price

    #CHOOSE THE MOST EXPENSIVE POSITION AND SELL IT#
    portfolio = sorted(portfolio, key = lambda x: x[0], reverse = True)
    soldpositions = [position for position in portfolio if position[7] == 'sold']
    soldpositions = sorted(portfolio, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)


    for position in portfolio:

        #Position must exist 
        if position[9] == True:
            print 'position b4 sold', position

            #Position's price must be LOWER than current price 
            #AND the difference between the position's price and current price must be greater than sellbuybuffer
            if abs(position[0] - price) <= sellbuybuffer:
                print 'does not meet sellbuybuffer' 

            if position[0] < price and abs(position[0] - price) >= sellbuybuffer:
                status = 'sold'

                #This is if we have no sold positions yet 
                if len(soldpositions) == 0:
                   get_row_data(price, date, position, totalstocks, capital, status, tokens)
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to assess the way in which the desired result for a given row depends on the data that is "higher up" in your set.  If a given row's output can be created based on *input* data in higher rows, you can save yourself some time and effort using something like `apply`.  But if your desired output for a given row depends on the *output* from earlier rows, then your problem is inherently ordered and as a result, you're unlikely to be able to do much better than a `for` loop even if you wind up with cleaner code.

Comment: ah, i see. i think it's the latter issue. my output does depend on output from earlier rows so it could be ordered.